# Is it possible to set an Image in Button with view?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm currently developing a simple tic-tac-toe game. Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghs6e.jpg) of the game.

The grid acts as a Button. So if I clicked the button, it would set the views to X's or O's according to the player's turn.

I used `((Button) v).setText("X");` and `((Button) v).setText("O");` to set the "views", but now I want to replace them with my own images of them.

As an information, I already tried `((Button) v).setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.x_icons);` but it just turns the button to the image!

So is it possible to add custom images/icons in or above the button with custom measurements of them?

Comment: Why not use an ```ImageButton``` ?

Comment: It failed to run

Comment: Can you be more specific? What failed to run?

Comment: Update: I have to hardcode the size in `ImageButton`, which is not good for the layout because it's not flexible. So, using a regular `Button` is a must.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to set an image on your button is better to use image button instead of button but if you have to use button i think you should change your image pixels because i think showing black background is because of your big image and because there is no 'scale type' for buttons it becomes black.

Comment: Tried it and then it failed too. I tried resizing the image before, but it keeps making the button black. I have no idea how to set the ```scaleType``` in the vector's XML

Comment: so how about 'image button' ?

Comment: Update: I have to hardcode the size in `ImageButton`, which is not good for the layout because it's not flexible. So, using a regular `Button` is a must.